# How to build a time based pricing system with overlaps

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I am currently working on a reservation system in PHP (Laravel 5) and I can't figure out how to build a time based pricing system that calculates the totalprice with overlaps. Reservations are stored with the following fields

```
Reservations (Table)

begindate_time (DateTime)
enddate_time (DateTime)
price (decimal(10,2))
```

I have a prices table to lookup the prices for the input begintime and endtime which looks like this:

```
Prices (Table)

id (INT)
price (decimal(10,2))
begin_time (time)
end_time (time)
dayOfTheWeeks (varchar(255))
```

The begin_time/end_time can vary from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59 and the dayOfTheWeeks is a string with days for instance monday,tuesday,wednesday. I know there should only be one value for each field, but I was to lazy to make a whole table for the days of the week.

Than you have a activity that is linked to a reservation that has different prices based on the time the activity this is linked to a price_activity table, because prices can have different activity's

```
activity_price (Table)    

id
activity_id (INT)
price_id (INT)
```

I tried to get the prices foreach activity and day like this, than I have them sorted and can try to loop through them and substract the endtime of the price minus the begintime of the reservation. This is what I came up with but it is not working...

```
foreach($activity->prices()->orderBy('begin_time','asc')->get() as $price){

            $whichDayArray = explode(',',$price->dayOfTheWeeks);

            if(in_array($dayToday,$whichDayArray)){

            $prices = array();

                if(strtotime($price->end_time) > strtotime($input['begintime']) && strtotime($price->begin_time) < strtotime($input['endtime'])){
                    $prices[] = array('id' => $price->id,'price' => $price->price,'beginTimePrice' => $price->begin_time, 'endTimePrice' => $price->end_time);
                }

            }

}
```

This is a lot of code and I have my prices that are overlapping my reservation now, but how do I calculate the amount of time a reservation is in a price. I think it can be done much easier and better than the above.

Comment: Have you actually tried anything to solve the problem, or are you just expecting a solution without any effort on your part?

Comment: @Bogdan I updated my post!

Comment: One approach is to build a static table containing ever hour and every weekday (24 x 7 rows) and join to it, grouping and counting rows joined with each price (on which day/hour matches each price) to determine how many hours to which each price applies.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks for your comment! The time is however not only in whole hours could be a half hour or quarter of an hour even minutes are allowed! So the problem still remains that you would have to calculate the amount of minutes that your reservation is in that hour, or you would have to insert a table with every minute of a day.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my own question. Hoping to help others with a similar problem, I would like to explain how I solved my problem.

After dumping my variables and making a visualization of the problem as shown below I found that the problem was related to my query.

```
[--pricerange1--][--pricerange2--][--pricerange2]
        [----------reservation-----------]
```

I have to get all the prices for a activity on a given day of the between the begintime of the reservation and the endtime of a reservation, after that I have to check if there is one price, two prices or more than 2 prices. Than calculate the number of hours that a reservation is in a range and multiply it by the price a range. The code for this will look like this:

```
$begintijd = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTime(16,30);
$eindtijd = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTime(20,30);

$activiteit = \App\Activiteit::find(1);

$prijzen = $activiteit->prices()->where('eindtijd','>=',$begintijd->toTimeString())->where('begintijd','<=',$eindtijd->toTimeString())->orderBy('begintijd','asc')->get();

$prijzenArray = array();

foreach($prijzen as $prijs){
    $whichDayArray = explode(',',$prijs->welkedagen);
    if(in_array('maandag',$whichDayArray)){
        $prijzenArray[] = array('prijs' => $prijs->prijs,'begintijdprijs' => $prijs->begintijd,'eindtijdprijs' => $prijs->eindtijd);
    }
}

$countPrijzen = count($prijzenArray);

if($countPrijzen == 1){
    $aantaluur = $begintijd->diffInMinutes($eindtijd) / 60;
    $totaalprijs = $aantaluur * $prijzenArray[0]['prijs'];
    echo('range1');
}

if($countPrijzen == 2){
    $aantaluurrange1 = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('G:i',$prijzenArray[0]['eindtijdprijs'])->diffInMinutes($begintijd) / 60;
    $aantaluurrange2 = $eindtijd->diffInMinutes(\Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('G:i',$prijzenArray[0]['eindtijdprijs'])) / 60;
    $totaalprijs = ($aantaluurrange1 * $prijzenArray[0]['prijs']) + ($aantaluurrange2 * $prijzenArray[1]['prijs']);
    echo('range2');
}

if($countPrijzen > 2){
    $aantaluurrange1 = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('G:i',$prijzenArray[0]['eindtijdprijs'])->diffInMinutes($begintijd) / 60;
    $prijsrange1 = $prijzenArray[0]['prijs'] * $aantaluurrange1;

    $prijsertussen = 0;
    for($prijs=1;$prijs<($countPrijzen-1);$prijs++){
        $aantaluurertussen = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('G:i',$prijzenArray[$prijs]['eindtijdprijs'])->diffInMinutes(\Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('G:i',$prijzenArray[$prijs]['begintijdprijs'])) / 60;
        $prijsertussen += $prijzenArray[$prijs]['prijs'] * $aantaluurertussen;
    }

    $aantaluurlaatsterange = $eindtijd->diffInMinutes(\Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('G:i',$prijzenArray[$countPrijzen-1]['begintijdprijs'])) / 60;
    $prijslaatsterange = $prijzenArray[$countPrijzen-1]['prijs'] * $aantaluurlaatsterange;

    $totaalprijs = $prijsrange1 + $prijsertussen + $prijslaatsterange;

}
```